# What does "in a car" mean after while?

Tags: grammar

I read this sentence:

> *Sally died while in a car i was driving!*

Can't understand here while separates 2 sentences and makes sense *at the same time*?

> *Sally died while i was driving in a car!*

But I am confused by in a car, for what / by what rule did we put it right after while?

Maybe this way we emphasize what exactly is **in the car**

Or maybe here while has a different meaning and the sentence without it would look like this :

> *Sally died in a car i was driving !*

I hope I asked the question correctly, i.e. I would like to understand why such a place of setting **in a car** in a sentence ?

Comment: "In a car" means "inside an automobile." "While" means *during time (that)* in that context, i.e., "Sally died *during time* "inside an automobile" *(that)* I was driving." It means I was driving a car and she was inside that car with me at the time that she died.

Comment: Please use caps for the pronoun "I".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in these cases I reach out for the context. I believe the author/writer tries to emphasize on the phrase "**I** WAS DRIVING". I mean in my opinion, the *car* is not important, it is ***me who drove the car***.

Example:

> I got my hand bitten while in a car *you* were driving.

It somehow indicates that there is a "*which*", or a "*that*" is omitted from the sentence

**UPDATE ON BEHALF OF @Kate Bunting**

for better understanding:

> Sally died while *[she was a passenger]* in a car *[that]* *I* was driving.

Comment: Alright ,i.e. the emphasis is placed on what is at the end, and not vice versa, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would understand it to mean

> *Sally died while [she was a passenger] in a car [that] I was driving.*